# Strip some words from a List collection

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing a selenium test against a web page which returns a table with some rows and columns showing payment data. I'm trying to strip some characters/words from the result of the XPATH i'm using because i dont need the part while doing an assertion (check if the data in table is correct).

Normally the webpage also returns a "Dropdown Button" as text (there is an icon), just before the identification number (e.g 168.3285.6021 as seen below).
What i used is it.set(it.next().replaceAll("DropDown Arrow ","")); so the DropDown Arrow text is replaced with nothing, which only works for the first line, but the other 2 lines don't get replaced. Any tips?

```
    public void check_receivals() {

    // Check how many lines and assert the size (from xpath)
    List<WebElement> Receivals = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='received-overview']//div[@class='bdpo-overview-table-row']/div[@class='claims']"));
    System.out.println(Receivals.size() + " receival lines found");
    assertEquals(7, Receivals.size());

    // Test data to compare against..aka expectedResultList
    List<String> expectedResultList = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedResultList.add ("168.3285.6021\n" + "Payment 2015\n" + "01-01-2015\n" + "€ 246");
    expectedResultList.add ("143.8407.8413\n" + "Payment 2015\n" + "01-01-2015\n" + "€ 233");
    expectedResultList.add ("154.2841.2407\n" + "Payment 2015\n" + "01-01-2015\n" + "€ 253");

    // Assert
    List<WebElement> ReceivalLines = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='received-overview']//div[@class='bdpo-overview-table-row']/div[@class='claims']"));
    List<String> ReceivalLines_List = ReceivalLines.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());

    ListIterator<String> it = ReceivalLines_List.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.set(it.next().replaceAll("DropDown Arrow ",""));

    assertEquals(ReceivalLines_List, expectedResultList);
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Just add "Dropdown Button" as part of your validation string. What if one day the icon disappears unexpectedly? Your test will pass but there will be a crucial UI element missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe issue is that you are modifying the iterator as you are working with it. I would suggest making the replace part of the stream operation using the map function.

```
List<String> ReceivalLines_List = ReceivalLines.stream().map(WebElement::getText).map(s -> s.replaceAll("DropDown Arrow ","")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```